# How to achieve shared customers across accounts in stripe ? (Clone customers across accounts)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, stripe-payments

I am working on stripe payments, where i require having a shared customer across different connected accounts, that are connected with the platform

I am using "*Express Accounts*" in stripe connect for connecting the connected accounts, that are linked with the platform account.

On the frontend (client-side) (Angular), using the "*Stripe Prebuilt checkout page*", for accepting payment and I am verifying the payment in webhooks(checkout.session.completed) at backend using Django Rest Framework.

I am using *Destination Charges*, for handling the payments and separate charges and transfers. (That i am able to achieve using stripe prebuilt checkout page by specifying payment_intent_data.application_fee_amount and payment_intent_data.transfer_data.destination)

> A destination charge means the charge is processed on the platform
> and then the funds are immediately and automatically transferred to
> the connected account’s pending balance.

Now I have a requirement where I need to have shared customers and share customers across the connected accounts,

1. Is it even possible to achieve shared customers using a stripe
   prebuilt checkout page?
2. If yes,  how can I achieve it?
3. Or Do I need to go with ["Custom payment flow"](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/integration-builder) for accepting a
   payment?

I tried to follow this article [Clone customers across accounts](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/cloning-saved-payment-methods) but I have not had any luck, unfortunately.

> With Connect, you can accomplish this by following three steps:
>
> 1. Storing customers, with a payment method, on the platform account
> 2. Making tokens to clone the payment method when it’s time to charge
>    the   customer on behalf of a connected account
> 3. Creating charges   using the   new tokens

1. For step 2. when do I need to create a token?
2. After which webhook event (payment_intent.succeeded ? or
   checkout.session.completed ?),  do I need to create the token and
   Clone customers across accounts?

I can also attach any code for your review and show you what I have tried by now.

Please let me know in the comments if you need it.

Comment: "I can also attach any code for your review and show you what I have tried by now." Please do so, if you have any. That helps always in not going over the same steps you've tried with no success.

Answer (score 0):

A big thing to clarify:

1. If you are using Destination Charges, your cards, customers and payments *all live on the Platform account*.

Therefore, it isn't clear why you want to create these "shared" customers on the Connect accounts, this sounds like you're approaching this the wrong way. You only need customers on Connect accounts if you're using *Direct Charges*.

> I tried to follow this article Clone customers across accounts but I have not had any luck, unfortunately.

This approach clones "tokens" for you i.e. clone a token from the Platform account to a Connect account. You cannot clone customers on Stripe, the API doesn't support it. You can manually create 'n' customers and have to manage the state between them yourself.

> After which webhook event (payment_intent.succeeded ? or checkout.session.completed ?), do I need to create the token and Clone customers across accounts?

If you're using Checkout, you use the `checkout.session.completed` event.

If you're using PaymentIntents and creating payments using Stripe Elements, you use `payment_intent.succeeded`

Please let me know if that clarifies things.

Comment: Okay, so I have an events platform where multiple society's exists, each society is connected with the platform, and each society has some events, a student can buy tickets from multiple societies, that's why I need to have shared customers.

Comment: This does not makes sense if I will create 5 customers with same email in 5 different stripe connected accounts, that's why I want to create a customer on platform using destination charges and share that customer on connected account as well, so they can see which students have bought tickets from their society events.

Comment: And the platform should be able to see all end customers,w ho have bought tickets from all societies, irrespective of events and societies.

Comment: "that's why I want to create a customer on platform using destination charges and share that customer on connected account" OK so it looks like you still want to use Destination Charges, just associate a corresponding Customer object in the connect account. Stripe doesn't offer this, there is no way to clone a Customer. You create a Customer on the Platform, one on the Connect account, and map them on your end (e.g. cus_123 on Platform maps to cus_654 on Connect acct_1)

Comment: "so they can see which students have bought tickets from their society events" -> the Connect account will only see a Transfer on their end, not a payment (due to the nature of Destination Charges). Moreoever, the "cloned" Customer you create will *not* be associated with this Transfer. I see the approach you're going for but it isn't supported in Stripe (i.e.  you can build it but it won't result in your desired outcome)

Comment: "just associate a corresponding Customer object in the connect account", could you please elaborate it programmatically by editing your answer ? That would be really helpful as I don't see how to accociate customer from platform to connected account using which stripe api ?

Comment: Could you please explain me, how can I achieve this 3 steps for clone customers across accounts as it is mentioned in stripe docs ? How I do this in my current scenario using stripe prebuilt checkout page ? I am confused if I should still go on with stripe prebuilt page or do I need to switch to custom payment flow, for what I am trying to achieve ?

Comment: As you said, using direct charges ? But then the customers will get created on connected accounts, I don't want that, I want the platform to be responsible for refunds and disputes, and I guess that is done using destination charges? Please correct me if I am wrong ?

Comment: "You create a Customer on the Platform, one on the Connect account, and map them on your end". How can I map the customers on stripe ? Could you please elaborate your explanation programmatically, even at high level (if possible) ?or do you meant that I have to map the customers at the application DB ?

Comment: "as I don't see how to accociate customer from platform to connected account using which stripe api" -> there is no way to associate a Customer object between platform and Connect account. Those are 2 unique entities with no connection between them. You choose to maintain a mapping in your database to say cus_1 in acct_1 is related to cus_2 in acct_2

Comment: I'd encourage you to talk to Stripe's support team at https://support.stripe.com/contact , as it is a bit difficult to unthread everything here :)

Comment: Okay, I will talk to stripe support, but as you better understand my scenario, could you please suggest me if I should still go on with stripe prebuilt page or do I need to switch to custom payment flow, for what I am trying to achieve ?

Comment: Both, the prebuilt Checkout or custom form with Elements, support "cloned tokens". The main misunderstanding here is that "cloning" in Stripe only supports cloned card tokens, NOT cloning Customers. That has never been supported, so any form of "cloning" that you try to do with Customers, you have to maintain that mapping on your end in your application code.

Comment: "the Connect account will only see a Transfer on their end, not a payment ", yes, i have created a transfer and i can see it on connected account, but in the customer it is shoing as none, could you please tell me how can i attach a customer(student), with the transfer, so connected account can see which customer has bought the tickets ? ALso how to attach metadata in trasfer under the payments section in stripe connected account ?
Please check the attached image: https://prnt.sc/vigp80

Comment: if i don't use destination charges, can i have 1 single customer account per student on platform level, and many tokens (each on a connected account) ? can i implement it programatically using that article " Clone customers across accounts " ?

Comment: as mentioned in that article, when i try to create a cutomer on platofrm, when shoul i do this 3 steps, after the checkout.session.complemented event, or when i create the checkout session object ?
when i created customer, it asks for a source,
customer = stripe.Customer.create(
  email='paying.user@example.com',
  source='tok_mastercard',
)
what will be the source in my case, and how i will get it ? as i am using checkout api and not the charges api, right ?

Comment: "could you please tell me how can i attach a customer(student), with the transfer" -> you cannot. This is not supported in the API. Transfer doesn't have the notion of "Customer". It by design means it is funds transferred from a Platform to a Connect account, regardless of Customer.

Comment: "ALso how to attach metadata in trasfer under the payments section in stripe connected account ?" Take the metadata from the Charge or PaymentIntent, update it on the Transfer object (using the Stripe-Account header)

Comment: > "can i have 1 single customer account per student on platform level, and many tokens (each on a connected account) ?" Yes you would use cloned tokens for this

Comment: "when i try to create a cutomer on platofrm, when shoul i do this 3 steps, after the checkout.session.complemented event" -> If you're using Checkout, you create a Customer before you create a CheckoutSession. If you do not, Checkout creates a Customer for you anyways (as part of its payment flow). With Checkout, you DO NOT attach a source / payment method to the Customer, Checkout does that for you

Comment: I'd encourage you read through the docs, implement things and see how it all works as I'm sensing some fundamental confusion on certain topics here :)